# How to escape special character in javascript split method?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

How to use `.split()` to split bottom string?

```
Love24|, LLC,Love 100|, LTE
```

It return as

```
Love24|, LLC
Love 100|, LTE
```

Comment: `Split()` isn't jquery method. It's function of javascript

Comment: jQuery has no .Split(). see; http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use regex to find target part of string in [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function of javascript.

```js
var str = "Love24|, LLC,Love 100|, LTE";
var match = str.match(/[\w\s]+\|,[\w\s]+/g);
console.log(match[0]);
console.log(match[1]);
```